# Deploying Rails App cheap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I'm making a Rails App, which I need to be online, but probably 1 or 2 people will use it at most. The app will organize photos + description uploaded by this user. The photos are aprox. 2 GB. I don't want to spend a lot of money on this, so my question is what is the best solution here? I hear Heroku is free but I can't upload photos in my App on Heroku and S3 costs money. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**host**

You can go with heroku, free plan should be enough for 2-5 person.

**image storage**

As you mentioned about S3 is not free or cheap, best solution is alternate of S3 is Cloudinary. It will allow you to upload around 5-7GB of data including bandwidth, and super fast.

[Cloudinary Link](https://cloudinary.com)

Alternates: Google Drive, Dropbox, Pcloud and etc... These all cloud storages maybe little slow in uploading or fetching but still free solution...

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted your answer but don't have enough points for it to show.

Comment: what about SSL on Heroku - is that additional cost? Or can I use letsencrypt?